# php string not working properly

Tags: php, html

My code in php is

```
echo $preference[0]."</br>";
echo '<p class="filter_entity">'.$preference[0].'<img src="' . base_url() . 'images/close-icon.png" onClick="filter_close()"></p>';
```

html out put is

```
Business
<img onclick="filter_close()" src="http://localhost/AEC/images/close-icon.png">
```

I want to put $preference[0] in filter_close() of my php code ... dont know how to do it .

Comment: onClick="filter_close('.$preference[0].') like this??

Comment: Are you sure it is html output of this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$param = $preference[0];
echo '<p class="filter_entity">'.$preference[0].'<img src="' . base_url() . 'images/close-icon.png" onClick="filter_close(\''.echo $param.'\')"></p>';
```

Just append the variable as a parameter of the js function

Comment: What do you want to pass to a php variable?

Comment: i did it like this ,,, your solution worked  onClick="filter_close(\''.$filter_name.'\',\''.$preference[2].'\')"

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

```php
echo "Some array item: {$array[0]}";
```